# Circles touching each other in a rectangle

Tags: geometry

[image]

In the solution of this question, why do all 3 points :- the vertex B, tangential point of quarter circle and external circle, center of circle need to be collinear ?

In my rough diagram, they are not being collinear, how can I prove these 3 points to be collinear?

[image]

Comment: Redraw your diagram more accurately. In a squeezed diagram both circles become ellipses.

Comment: You should use Geogebra for example to draw your diagrams...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As noted in a comment, using a sketch that you yourself call a “rough diagram” is leading you astray. However, even with an accurate diagram, the question remains valid: *why* are the centres of the two circles collinear with the point where they touch?

When we say that two circles “touch externally”, we mean that they have a common tangent line at that point, with their centres on opposite sides of this line. **A radius of a circle is always perpendicular to the tangent line it meets on the circumference.** ([Euclid III.18](http://aleph0.clarku.edu/%7Edjoyce/java/elements/bookIII/propIII18.html))

[image: A diagram of the problem. The rectangle, large quarter circle, and small full circle are shown with solid lines. Their shared tangent line, and several radiuses, are shown with dashed lines.]

Call the small circle’s centre $O$, and the touch point $T$. The two circles’ radiuses $BT$ and $OT$ are both perpendicular to a third line, their common tangent, so $BT \parallel OT$. And they share point $T$, so they are collinear. ∎

Comment: Thank you, how did you get BT || OT , is it possible for you to make a diagram and explain, I am not really getting how did you prove the collinearity in the last part of your answer ?

Comment: @Fin27 I’ll try and put a diagram together when I have a chance, but in words: Two lines that are both *perpendicular* to a third must be *parallel* to each other. (Two posts set upright on the same floor must be parallel.) And parallel lines that share even one point are, in fact, the “same” line—they are collinear.

Comment: Understood, Thanks a lot :)... I have one more extension to my doubt , will this line from vertex B passing through the center of smaller circle also touch the opposite vertex D as well ?

Comment: @Fin27 (Oops, thought I replied to this already…) No. D and O are opposite vertices of a square with two radiuses of the small circle as edges. So its diagonal DO is at 45° to DC and DA. But rectangle ABCD isn’t square, so its diagonal BD is *not* at 45° to DC or DA.

Comment: Thank you so much :)